# Issue Deleting documents using wildcards in C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder

I'm using this function to delete files if there's a wild card involved
I made an application in c++ builder 6 that reads a file with commands
and then execute them the problem is that when I put a different directory the function reads and delete the file with the commands
example
the file is hola.txt

when I do ofstream("hola2.txt") or ofstream ("C:\path\hola3.txt"), it works fine when it comes to delete
I use remove("hola.txt") it works but I can't use wildcards with that one
if I do WildDeleteFiles("*.txt")
it deletes every txt file in the application folder
but when I do WildDeleteFiles("C:\path*.txt") doesn't delete the txt file in that directory but instead only erase the txt file with the commands
this is the function

```
void WildDeleteFiles(const char* direcc)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
    HANDLE hFind;

    hFind = FindFirstFile(direcc, &fd);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        ShowMessage("No files found!");
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            DeleteFile(fd.cFileName);
        }
        while (FindNextFile(hFind, &fd));
        ShowMessage("Files deleted!");
        cmpi++;
        rfi = 1;
    }
}
```

and this is how a call it later:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Image4Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    WildDeleteFiles(TStrings1->Cells[1][0].c_str());
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: WTH is _"c++ builder 6"_ please??

Comment: Check out https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c%2B%2B+builder+6, @πάνταῥεῖ.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt PFFRRRR ...

Comment: The fd structure holds the file name only(no path),  you need add path information to delete files correctly.

Comment: Well, @πάνταῥεῖ, you've been here long enough to know that you deserve "STFW" as answer to your question, in case that's what you were objecting to in such an eloquent manner. :-)

Comment: This isn't WhatsApp. Please do use proper punctuation.

Comment: @Tim3880 thank you, didn't know 
Solved!

Comment: You don't call `FindClose` as you are expected to. So you have a leak.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

- Firstly, that IDE you use is horribly outdated and you won't find much support for it today. You should definitely upgrade.
- Secondly, you almost don't check for any errors at all, which isn't good. If you step through the code and check against the documentation, you will also find that `FindFirstFile()`/`FindNextFile()` does exactly what it's documented to do, in particular it doesn't do any recursive search for files. If you want that, either implement it yourself or use shell functions like `SHFileOperation()`. In any case, searching for "Windows C++ delete file tree" should give you a bunch of hints where to look.

Comment: This feels like a comment rather than an answer. So what if the IDE is old. The code would work (or not work) just the same with any compiler. There is no `SHDeleteFile`. Telling the user to search the web is fine for a comment, but doesn't really get it done as an answer. I know the question is weak, but that's not excuse enough.

Answer (score 0):

The `WIN32_FIND_DATA::cFileName` field only contains the found filename, not a full path to the file.  As such, you are passing relative filenames to `DeleteFile()` that are affected by the calling process's current working directory.  That is why you are having trouble deleting files in the correct folder.  You need to pass full paths to `DeleteFile()` to avoid that.

Try something more like this:

```
void WildDeleteFiles(const String &direcc)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
    HANDLE hFind;

    hFind = FindFirstFile(direcc.c_str(), &fd);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
            ShowMessage("No files found!");
        else
            ShowMessage("Error finding files!");
    }
    else
    {
        String path = ExtractFilePath(direcc);

        do
        {
            if ((fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0)
                DeleteFile(path + fd.cFileName);
        }
        while (FindNextFile(hFind, &fd));

        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        FindClose(hFind);

        if (dwErr == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
            ShowMessage("Files deleted!");
        else
            ShowMessage("Error finding files!");

        cmpi++;
        rfi = 1;
    }
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Image4Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    WildDeleteFiles(TStrings1->Cells[1][0]);
}
```